# python: unexpected behavior from struct pack()

Tags: python

I'm having trouble using the `struct.pack()` for packing an integer.

With

```
struct.pack("BIB", 1, 0x1234, 0)
```

I'm expecting

```
'\x01\x00\x00\x034\x12\x00'
```

but instead I got

```
'\x01\x00\x00\x004\x12\x00\x00\x00'
```

I'm probably missing something here. Please help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
'\x01\x00\x00\x004\x12\x00\x00\x00'
                 ^ this '4' is not part of a hex escape
```

is actually the same as:

```
'\x01\x00\x00\x00\x34\x12\x00\x00\x00'
```

Because the ASCII code for "4" is 0x34.

Because you used the default (native) format, Python used native alignment for the data, so the second field was aligned to offset 4 and 3 zeroes were added before it.

To get a result more like what you wanted, use the format `>BIB` or `<BIB` (for big-endian or little-endian respectively) This gives you `'\x01\x00\x00\x12\x34\x00'` or `'\x01\x34\x12\x00\x00\x00'`. Neither of those are exactly what you specified, because the example you gave was not proper big-endian or little-endian representation of 0x1234.

See also: section [Byte Order, Size, and Alignment](https://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html#byte-order-size-and-alignment) in the documentation.

Answer (score 2):

From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html#struct-alignment)

> **Note** By default, the result of packing a given C struct includes pad bytes in order to maintain proper alignment for the C types
>   involved; similarly, alignment is taken into account when unpacking.
>   This behavior is chosen so that the bytes of a packed struct
>   correspond exactly to the layout in memory of the corresponding C
>   struct. To handle platform-independent data formats or omit implicit
>   pad bytes, use standard size and alignment instead of native size and
>   alignment: see Byte Order, Size, and Alignment for details.

You can get your desired result by forcing the byte order. (`chr(0x34)` == `'4'`)

```
>>> struct.pack(">BIB", 1, 0x1234, 0)
'\x01\x00\x00\x124\x00'
```